# Update Schema for DataFrame in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with the following schema

```
root
 |-- col_a: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_b: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_c_a: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_c_b: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_d: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_e: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_f: string (nullable = false)
```

now I want to convert the Schema for this data frame to something like this.

```
root
 |-- col_a: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_b: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_c: struct (nullable = false)
     |-- col_c_a: string (nullable = false)
     |-- col_c_b: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_d: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_e: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col_f: string (nullable = false)
```

I can able to do this with the help of `map` transformation by explicitly fetching the value of each column from `row` type but this is very complex process and does not look good So,

is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an in-built struct function with the definition :

```
def struct(cols: Column*): Column
```

You can use it like :

```
df.show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+

df.withColumn("struct_col", struct($"a", $"b")).show
+---+---+----------+
|  a|  b|struct_col|
+---+---+----------+
|  1|  2|     [1,2]|
|  2|  3|     [2,3]|
+---+---+----------+
```

The schema of the new dataframe being :

```
 |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- struct_col: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
```

In you case, you can do something like :

```
df.withColumn("col_c" , struct($"col_c_a", $"col_c_b") ).drop($"col_c_a").drop($"col_c_b")
```

Comment: how can i change schema of struct_col.a